# C# NullReferenceException with DiscordSharp

Tags: c#

Fairly new to C#, and as a beginning project, I made a discord bot for one of my teams.

Here's the code:

```
using DiscordSharp;
if (e.MessageText.StartsWith("!soldier "))
{
    bool isadmin = false;
    List<DiscordRole> roles = e.Author.Roles;
    foreach (DiscordSharp.Objects.DiscordRole role in roles)
    {
        if (Blacklist.Contains(e.Author.Username) == false)
        {
            if (role.Name.Contains("Moderator") | role.Name.Contains("▌▌▌▌⚡ High Command"))
            {
                isadmin = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isadmin)
    {
        e.Channel.SendMessage("[Finding..]");
        string str1 = e.MessageText.Substring(e.MessageText.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
        var member = e.Channel.Parent.GetMemberByUsername(str1, false);

        var server = client.GetServersList().Find(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "Army of the Galactic Republic");
        List<DiscordRole> Roles = e.Author.Roles;
        foreach (DiscordSharp.Objects.DiscordRole role in roles)
        {
            var Role = Roles.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "Soldier");
            Console.WriteLine(Role);
            if (member == null)
            {
                e.Channel.SendMessage("invalid user");
            }
            else
            {
            }
            Console.WriteLine(member);
            Console.WriteLine(server);
            e.Channel.SendMessage("[Found..]");
            e.Channel.SendMessage("[Found user: " + str1);
            client.AssignRoleToMember( server,  role,  member);
            e.Channel.SendMessage("[Roled] user: " + str1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Channel.SendMessage("Denied action.");
    }
}
```

After doing some tests, it appears that `server` was `null`. If anyone can help fix it, I would gladly appreciate it!

Comment: SO has functionality to include code snippets - please use it instead of a third party service, especially since it's not a huge amount of code. Thanks!

Comment: Re-read your code here: `x.Name.ToLower() == "Army..."`. You're lower-casing the server name, and then comparing it to a string with capital letters. It will *never* match, and so you will never find the server. Compare it to `"army of the galactic republic"`

Comment: Thanks @Rob! That seemed to fix the server issue. Now the issue is trying to get it to give the correct role.

Comment: You'll notice you have the exact same issue with your roles ;)

Comment: As a suggestion: you might want to adopt the pattern of: `x.Name.Equals("Soldier", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` rather than using `.ToLower()` and comparing

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the suggestion! I switched out ``.ToLower()`` with your suggestion, but it still gives a random, yet certain, kind of role to the user it's being applied to. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: Your code is looping through each role the user has. Then it looks for the Soldier role (but does nothing with it, except printing it). I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - but really, you'll just need to think for a few minutes about what you're trying to do. It's likely you don't need to loop through the users roles (as you're simply assigning them a role), so you can remove that loop entirely. Then use `Role` instead of your `role`, which should get you most of the way there. The rest simply comes down to debugging